# Merge multiple csv files to one with specific columns only

Tags: python, csv

**Task needs to be done:**

- I have multiple csv files, I want to combine them to one with specific rows (unfortunately my csv doesn't have specific column headings, instead it has rows, I will share a screenshot for more visibility).
  The merged csv file should contain columns (Image name, HITId, Confidence, Sequence("EASTING","NORTHING","DIST"))

[image: Example of one image in excel file]

*I have around 40 images per excel, and in total I have more than 40 excel sheets*

Here is an example of the one csv file I am looking for:

[image: merged csv file example]

**What have been done so far:**

- I was able to merge the files, here is an example of the code

```
import csv
import os
os.chdir("/home/.../Annotation")


extension = 'csv'
files = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
line_count = 0

for file in files:
    with open(file, 'r') as f1:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f1,delimiter= ',')
        with open ('merged_csv.csv','a', newline='') as f2:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(f2,delimiter=',')
            if line_count == 0:
                csv_writer.writerow(["imagename","HITId","Confidence","EASTING","NORTHING","DIST"])
                line_count +=1
                
            next(csv_reader, None)
            for row in csv_reader:
                data =[file[:-4]] + row
                csv_writer.writerow(data)
```

Note:
If anything is not clear, please let me know!! I tried my best to solve it! I can't seems to be thinking the correct way to solve it

Comment: have you tried [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)? You can merge files on a single row using `pandas.merge`. Also can you please share an example file(s) and your final expected output? Images are not the best.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to use raw text versions of your CSV file (load it in a text editor, not Excel). We could then see the actual format and also copy/paste it to test your script